# What is the difference between measurement protocol event tracking and analytics.js or tag manager event tracking?

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking, measurement-protocol

This confuses me. Let's say I want to integrate Google Analytics with my server-side web application. I basically want to track the events by users.

To do this I can use Measurement protocol event tracking with HTTP requests and on the other hand use analytics.js or Google tag manager to track events.

But I'm not sure which one to choose because couldn't understand the difference between them. What is the major difference ?

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that the code of the `analytics.js` library just put it on the page and the pageviews will be tracked automatically with the various information relating to the resolution of the user's device, host name, page path, etc... while with the `measurement protocol` you have to indicate the parameters manually (this protocol is in fact useful for tracking those systems where the library code cannot be used, for example IOT).

Comment: i think i get it. So there is no thing like if I use analytics it is better for me or otherwise ? And more thing is like measurement protocol is being used for cross-device tracking which you also mentioned about that which are IOT things, am I right ?

Comment: If you can use the library you should use that. The measurement protocol does not resolve the cross-device.

Comment: I just realized something that I cannot use analytics.js for server-side ? In google docs it is stated that measurement protocol is for server side integration. However for client-side it says we can use analytics.js